# How to Add: TTC instead of HT in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-modules

How i can Add TTC(including taxes) instead of HT(excluding taxes)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBHGL.png)

i use defaut theme in prestashop 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Navigate to

   > Localization -> Taxes

and scroll down to `Tax options` section.

2. Activate `Enable Tax` and `Display tax` in the shopping cart options, if they are disabled. Save changes.
3. After that you need to configure a price display method for customer groups. Go to

   > Customers -> Groups

and click `Edit` on the group you want to modify.

4. Find `Price display` method option and select `Price included`. Save changes.